# Cannot remove the account password?

Tags: windows-10

I want to remove my account password on my windows machine but I couldn't handle it.

I tried with `netplwiz` but it didn't work. I also tried from general settings(I set password field as blank).

When I reboot my machine I am still seeing the password confirmation screen. Is there a different way to deal with this? Does anybody know DOS command for this action?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Verify the account is not linked to a Microsoft Account.  You will have to give us more than "it didn't work" otherwise we won't be able to help.  If you looking to configure your system to automatically log into your profile, that is possible with or without a password, and takes less than 30 seconds to configure.  However, it is not clear from what you have asked, if that is actually what your attempting to do.

Comment: `net user "username" ""`

Comment: did you try a blank password at the password screen? Are you trying to get windows to load straight to the desktop with no password?

Comment: What about Righ click Start Menu->Computer Management->System too->Local user and group->User->Right click user->set password->input nothing and apply?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why windows asks for a password.

- You have more than 1 active accounts on the computer
- Your account is a Microsoft Account
- Your account has a password.

If your account has a password, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd> and select Change Password.

Enter your old password in the above field, and leave the other passwords blank such that they are empty. It will remove the password from your account.

If you have a Microsoft Account, you cannot clear the password. If you have more than one account, it doesn't matter if your account has a password or not, but without a password, you login if you simply click your account.